# How to get Spring to execute a method when the bean is initialized?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, initialization, postconstruct

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE.  I have a class (annotated with `@Service`), in which I have a method

```
package org.mainco.subco.myproject.service;
…
@PostConstruct
public void initCaches()
{
    LOG.info("initiating caches.");
    …
}   // initCaches
```

However, this method is never getting called, despite the fact the service class is included in a `<context:component-scan />`.  I have this in my application context file …

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco" />
```

How do I get a method to be executed when my bean is created/initialized?  I don’t care if its `@PostConstruct`, if there’s another way or annotation i need. that.  The key thing is that the method have access to autowired Spring beans.

Comment: First question, is your bean getting autowired? Coz i doubt thats happening

Comment: Sure is, is the answer.

Comment: With the above provided information its hard to tell what the problem is with the post construct. Can you post some more of your service class. Does it have `@transactional` annotation etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did instead was implement the "InitializingBean " interface ...

```
implements InitializingBean
```

and overriding the "afterPropertiesSet" method solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use Spring's `aop` ([Aspect Orientation](http://java2practice.com/2013/02/02/82/)) functionality?

```
<aop:config>
   <aop:aspect ref="service">
      <aop:pointcut id="myotherbeans" 
         expression="execution(* package.name.myotherbeans.initializers(...))"
      />
      <aop:before
         pointcut-ref="myotherbeans"
         method="initCaches" 
      />
   </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

You'll need to include `xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop`